# Combine delegates with an OR operator

Tags: c#, lambda

*Looking up values in two different tables with LinqToSQL, and combining the results based on what is found in what resultset.*

How can I **combine two Funcs** based on given conditions:

```
 // a filter for a LinqToSQL query:
 Func<ComputerDetail, bool> filter;

 // declare the default filter
 filter = x => x.ComputerName.Contains(searchTerm);
```

then **if a condition is met** it would like to add the below lambda to the above one:

```
 x => computernames.Contains(x.ComputerName)
```

so it both would result in:

```
 x => computernames.Contains(x.ComputerName)) ||
      x.ComputerName.Contains(searchTerm);
```

Creating a multicast delegate with a plus operator almost seems to do it, 
however, I am not sure how to **apply the OR** (||) in this case:

```
 filter += computernames.Contains(x.ComputerName)
```

**note:** `computernames` is a `List<String>` , `ComputerName` is a property of `ComputerDetail` which is a Class representing a View in *LinqToSQL*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's LINQ to SQL, you don't want to combine two *delegates* - you want to combine two *expression trees*. Otherwise all of your filtering will be done on the client side.

If that's the case, I believe you basically just need [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) - use `predicate1.Or(predicate2)` to combine two predicates.

If you *really* want the delegate form, you can take the same code and just change all the signatures to use delegates instead of expression trees.

Comment: Excuse my misterminology. predicate1.Or(predicate2) just removed a lot of future sloppy code from my app, Expression trees will do fine here.

Comment: @CasparKleijne: It's not just a matter of terminology though - you need to change your declaration to `Expression<Func<ComputerDetail, bool>>` as otherwise it will work, but having fetched everything from the database...

Comment: Jon, thank you I understand, The functions are passed as parameters to built an expression, just before the query is send to the database. I receive only the data I need at that moment. Is it better to use expressions all the way?

Comment: @CasparKleijne: Absolutely - have a look at the SQL being generated; if you're using delegates, that filtering can *only* be done client-side; expression trees allow the filtering to be done at the database.

Comment: Jon, thanks, checked, you just saved me from doing something terrible. I indeed forgot that deferred execution of the queries only works with the expressions.

Comment: @CasparKleijne: No, deferring query evaluation happens either way - but *translating* the query to SQL only happens with expression trees :)